# Minimizing Average Pairwise Squared Euclidean Norm

Tags: algorithms

I'm pretty new to programming and computer science, but I was wondering if there was any good way to approach the following problem: For a set of 2n points (not necessarily unique) in R^k (assume each entry is positive), I want an algorithm which will partition the set into n pairs such that the average Euclidean distance squared is minimized.

EDIT: Edited for clarity.

Comment: Huh?  Could you give an example of the problem and correct answer?  As it is, I can't quite picture the problem domain to be able to think through how to do to this.

Comment: @MichaelT Sure. Consider four individuals. The individuals have vectors (0,1), (1,0), (1,1), and (1/2,1). Just brute forcing it, we get that pairing (1/2,1) and (0,1) together and (1,0) and (1,1) together gives us 2((1/2)^2+1^2)/4 = 5/8 which is less than anything else. I'll edit it to make it clearer.

I suppose it'd be easier to think of the individuals as just the points themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for a *minimum weight perfect matching* in a complete weighted undirected graph. Your *2n* points are the vertices, and each pair of vertices has an undirected edge between them with weight equal to the Euclidean distance between the points.

The [Blossom Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blossom_algorithm) can solve this problem. According to [(Kolmogorov, 2009)](http://pub.ist.ac.at/~vnk/papers/BLOSSOM5.html) linked from the Wikipedia page, the best known complexity bound is O(|V||E| + |V| log |V|), which in your case would be O(n^3) because it's a complete graph.

Reference: Kolmogorov, 2009. Blossom V: a new implementation of a minimum cost perfect matching algorithm. *Mathematical Programming Computation*, vol. 1, issue 1, pp. 43-67.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know where I can find the complexity bound? I seem  to only be finding the bounds for Blossom IV in the paper.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make it work: try every possible pairing through brute-force backtracking (recursive implementation).
2. Make sure you are not testing the same pairing more than once (there are some pitfalls there). And try to derive your algorithms complexity. I think it is 2k(n!).

Now you can think about more clever solutions, and you have a reference implementation to check correctness and speed improvement.

1. By comparing with your best-solution-so-far, you can skip entire parts of your search space (=pruning). Eg. If you have an incomplete pairing, and the sum of square distances is already higher than your best score, don't try to compete this pairing. With some precalculations (like finding the nearest m neighbors for every point) you change the search order so that you find a reasonable solution early. This will drastically increase the pruning and speed up the implementation.
2. Or, try something completely different: Start with any complete pairing, and then look for local optimizations: if you can improve 2 pairs (AB & CD) by switching their partners (either AC & BD or AD & BC), then you have improved the total solution too. You repeat this, until you can't find such a pair or pairs anymore.  (EDIT: Actually, this approach is not guaranteed to find the best solution. It can get 'stuck' in a local minimum).